# How can I delay the onkey event until the function has finished executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Basically I'm making a space invaders type game in python and for some reason, it's still allowing the user to press the spacebar no matter what I do. Therefore, I would like to see what kind of ideas you guys have since I have no idea what to do to make this work.

Also I have tried creating a delay variable so that if the delay variable is true then it will execute the onkey event but unfortunately it didn't work.
I have also tried making the both the function and the onkey sleep via the time library but also didn't work

```
import turtle

# Making the window and its proporties
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Galaxy Wars")
wn.bgcolor("black")

# adding the images to the shape function so that it will recongize them as a shape
turtle.register_shape("Spaceship.gif")
turtle.register_shape("invader2.gif")
turtle.register_shape("Laser beam.gif")

# creating the fighter jet and then puting it down
fighter = turtle.Turtle()
fighter.shape("Spaceship.gif")
fighter.penup()
fighter.setposition(0,-270)
fighter.setheading(90)

# create the laser
laser = turtle.Turtle()
laser.speed(0)
laser.setheading(90)
laser.hideturtle()
laser.shape("Laser beam.gif")
laser.penup()

# how far the fighter teleports each time a key is pressed
fighttp = 20

# delay
delay = "F"

# creating functions that either adds or substracts the current position
def up():
    y = fighter.ycor()
    y += fighttp
    if y > -130:
        y = -130
    fighter.sety(y)

def left():
    x = fighter.xcor()
    x -= fighttp
    if x < -370:
        x = -370
    fighter.setx(x)

def down():
    y = fighter.ycor()
    y -= fighttp
    if y < -300:
        y = -300
    fighter.sety(y)

def right():
    x = fighter.xcor()
    x += fighttp
    if x > 360:
        x = 360
    fighter.setx(x)


# give the player the laser beam to perform the pew pew on the bad guys just like the original game

def shoot():
    if delay == "F":
        delay == "T"
        laser.speed(0)
        laser.setposition(fighter.xcor(), fighter.ycor() + 20)
        laser.showturtle()
        laser.speed(3)
        laser.forward(500)
        laser.hideturtle()
        delay == "F"


# turtle listens for the keys and then it moves according to the function and key pressed
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(left, "a")
turtle.onkey(right, "d")
turtle.onkey(up, "w")
turtle.onkey(down, "s")
if delay == "F":
    turtle.onkey(shoot, "space")



wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip the `delay` variable.  Instead we can turn on and off the key event within the key event handler:

```
def shoot():
    turtle.onkey(None, "space")  # disable handler inside handler

    laser.speed(0)
    laser.setposition(fighter.xcor(), fighter.ycor() + 20)
    laser.showturtle()
    laser.speed(3)
    laser.forward(500)
    laser.hideturtle()

    turtle.onkey(shoot, "space")
```

Below is a rework of your code with various style changes and optimizations:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# Making the window and its properties
screen = Screen()
screen.title("Galaxy Wars")
screen.bgcolor('black')

# Adding images to the shape function so that it will recognize them as a shape
screen.register_shape("Spaceship.gif")
screen.register_shape("Laser beam.gif")

# Create the fighter jet and then put it down
fighter = Turtle()
fighter.shape("Spaceship.gif")
fighter.penup()
fighter.sety(-270)
fighter.setheading(90)

# Create the laser
laser = Turtle()
laser.hideturtle()
laser.shape("Laser beam.gif")
laser.setheading(90)
laser.penup()

# How far the fighter teleports each time a key is pressed
fighttp = 20

# creating functions that either adds or subtracts the current position
def up():
    y = fighter.ycor() + fighttp
    if y > -130:
        y = -130
    fighter.sety(y)

def left():
    x = fighter.xcor() - fighttp
    if x < -370:
        x = -370
    fighter.setx(x)

def down():
    y = fighter.ycor() - fighttp
    if y < -300:
        y = -300
    fighter.sety(y)

def right():
    x = fighter.xcor() + fighttp
    if x > 360:
        x = 360
    fighter.setx(x)

# Give player laser beam to perform the pew pew on the bad guys just like the original game

def shoot():
    screen.onkey(None, 'space')  # disable handler inside handler

    laser.speed('fastest')
    laser.setposition(fighter.xcor(), fighter.ycor() + 20)
    laser.showturtle()
    laser.speed('slow')
    laser.forward(500)
    laser.hideturtle()

    screen.onkey(shoot, 'space')

# Listen for keys and move according to the function and key pressed
screen.onkey(left, 'a')
screen.onkey(right, 'd')
screen.onkey(up, 'w')
screen.onkey(down, 's')
screen.onkey(shoot, 'space')
screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```